# Extending UIScrollView and Monitoring Scroll Events

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm wanting to implement some custom, reusable and efficient scroll behavior in an iPhone app so I'm extending *UIScrollView* with my custom control and wish to track scroll movements.

Now I'm aware that I could probably assign my custom control as a *UIScrollViewDelegate* and internally respond to *scrollViewDidScroll* calls but this doesn't feel correct to me (I may be wrong).

It doesn't feel correct as the delegate is aimed at application specific UI logic and controls should be a level above this. It would also mean I'd need to relay delegate calls out if an application class assigned itself as a delegate too which seems inefficient.

As a direct descendant of *UIScrollView* I'd expect to be able to override the method that triggers the *scrollViewDidScroll* delegate call, or be given access to a template method, or listen out for scroll events, but I can't see any such options.

Looking at the *UITableView.h* file, *UITableView* doesn't seem to set itself as a *UISCrollViewDelegate* so I'm wondering how it manages this (I'm assuming as it recycles cells it must track their position relative to the visible bounds).

I'm pretty new to this platform so I may be missing something obvious. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution?

Comment: I ran with implementing UIScrollViewDelegate in the end, and double delegating out the UIScrollViewDelegate actions from my custom component.

I think Rob's answer below sounds along the right path, but it came a bit late for the work I was doing so I didn't have a chance to explore it unfortunately.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found it!! (completely by accident)

I had resigned myself to assign my UIScrollView subclass as a delegate to super then implement the *scrollViewDidScroll:* delegate method, however part way through implementing I got an exception in the middle of my scrollViewDidScroll method.. One quick look at the stack trace showed me that my delegate method was actually being called from the **setContentOffset:**

It turns out, if you ***override setContentOffset:*** you get a call every time the scroll view moves! and it comes with a handy contentOffset struct to tell you where the scroll view currently is :)

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset
{
    [super setContentOffset:contentOffset];

    NSLog(@"ViewDidScroll: %f, %f", contentOffset.x, contentOffset.y);
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution. You saved my day :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I agree with your original assessment. If you're changing the scrolling logic itself (rather than responding to scrolling) then that's a subclass, not a delegate.

UIScrollView is designed to be subclassed and includes a small discussion about it in the reference. In particular it suggestions overriding `-touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContent:`, `pagingEnabled` and `touchesShouldCancelInContentView:`, which are probably where you want to do the work you're describing.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt you should definitely go for the delegate methods, however sometimes (i've only needed to do it now in the last 5 years of iOS dev) subclassing is the way to go.

Jo-el's answer is correct for Obj-C. Here it is in Swift:

```
class FeedScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
        willSet(newContentOffset) {
            print("About to set Offset: \(newContentOffset)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this method run once or many times (continuously as long as it’s scrolling) per scroll?

Answer (score 0):

> (I may be wrong)

I think you are. Without understanding the details of your app, the delegate methods sound like exactly what you want. Bear in mind that the controller (`UIViewController` subclass) can also be the delegate of its view.

Answer (score 0):

I think the delegate relay is what you want. It would let you use the published API, which is usually recommended rather than overriding functions you're not really supposed to know about. I agree that it does seem messier than it should have to be, but if the hooks in UIScrollViewDelegate are what you need for your customizations then it sounds like that's your best bet.

You can also provide your own custom delegate object/protocol to whatever UIViewController is using your scroll view to do some view specific logic too.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following protocol to listen to scroll position:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"scroll");
}
```

See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006923-CH3-SW3) (Apple docs on UIScrollViewDelegate).

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993280/how-to-detect-when-a-uiscrollview-has-finished-scrolling/20017639#20017639) also (some code to set up the delegate).