# iPhone App how to programmatically detect Scrolling of scrollview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiscrollview

iPhone App how to  programmatically detect Scrolling of scrollview?
iPhone App how to check scrollview did Scroll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the delegate method:

```
scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)
```

In your implementation of that method, you can check the content offset value for the new position.

The docs are here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html

Also, if you just want to know the result of the scrolling after it is finished, see this answer for a similar question:

[How to detect when a UIScrollView has finished scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993280/how-to-detect-when-a-uiscrollview-has-finished-scrolling/1857162#1857162)

Answer (score 0):

You should check [UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html).