# Play video in UITableview Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In one of my application i have to play video in UITableviewcell, at a time in one cell one video will play and when scroll UITableview and cell hide video should stop. My project is in Objc.

any suggestion for any third party?

thanks in advance

Comment: for playing video in uitableviewcell, what you are using? is that webview or anyother mediaplayer?

Comment: Well, I am not sure about any 3rd party SDK. But you can refer this post on SO. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825994/play-video-on-uitableviewcell-when-it-is-completely-visible

Comment: @R.Mohan i have used one third party app but it creates issue so i m looking for another alternet

Comment: what you have tried ? add that code in question!

Comment: @Lion i have tried ZFPlayer third party app but it creates some issue in my scenarios

Comment: @Hardik A check my answer and try it. if it works for you, accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use UIWebView in that cell, it will work fine

```
 NSString *baseUrl = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/";
    NSString *videoUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseUrl,embedCode];
    videoUrl = [videoUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,videoUrl, 300.0, 200.0];
    UIWebView *videoWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 10.0, width-16, (width-16)/1.8)];
    [videoWebView setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
    videoWebView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = YES;
    videoWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    videoWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    [videoWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.contentView addSubview:videoWebView];
```