# UIRefreshControl cancel touch on top of custom cell - Objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have an issue with my `UIRefreshControl` : after the first time it was triggered, it cancels touch on top of my first custom cell (even if it is hidden), like if it was invisible.
If I remove it from superview, then add it again, the issue is still there.

Actually I have a `UITableView` that is populated with some data. The user can refresh the table view by pulling it and for that I've added an `UIRefreshControl` to my table view like this in `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.35 green:0.78 blue:0.98 alpha:1.0];
[_tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

I've not added selector to the refreshControl object because I want the tableView to refresh only when the user stopped touching the screen. So for that I've added this ScrollView's delegate method :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {

    if (self.refreshControl.isRefreshing) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self refreshTable];

            });

        });

    }

}
```

And here is my refresh method :

```
- (void)refreshTable {

    //refresh code

    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

}
```

I don't want to put my app online with this issue, even if this does not block user to use it !

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: What do you mean by `because I want the tableView to refresh only`? you would refresh by dragging the UITableView only, whats the point doing it through scrollview delegate?

Comment: @iphoniclike it was said, " I want the tableView to refresh only when the user stop touching the screen". If I don't do that way (I mean if I add a selector), the reloadData won't wait that the user stop touching the screen. Is there any way to do this without ScrollView's delegate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by going to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857162/2450887)

So effectively in my case I did not have to add a selector, just implement those UIScrollViewDelegate's method :)