# UICollectionView reload every second

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

My sport app keeps track of who is on and off the field, and for how long. I normally have 20-30 people to swap around, during training time. I have a timer to reload the visible cells of the collection view every second. The whole collection view reload can cost between 120-150ms.

The scrolling performance is good, however, sometimes the tapping to swap players does not respond. I think that is when the collection view is trying to reload the cells.

I can see there might a couple of ways:

- Use UITableView, with each row to have 4 different elements.
- Use UIScrollView, and preload all elements there. We used to use [KKGridView](https://github.com/keichan34/KKGridView) library here, but it is way outdated. That is why we move to UICollectionView after 6-7 years

Have anyone had the same issue, and which way should provide the acceptable level of efficiency but not too complex to implement (to reduce the number of bugs)

[image: CollectionView]

Comment: you could disable reload while scrolling, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/993304/22147

Comment: that wouldn't help, I don't have problems with scrolling

Comment: whoops, sorry, missed that. you could reload the cell yourself without asking the collection view to do it

Comment: why dont just update the cell's view instead of reload whole visible cell?

Comment: Perhaps you could show some code as it isn't exactly clear what you are reloading; reloading the entire collection view isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Tj3n: you mean to call [collectionView visibleCells] and then update the cell's element?

Comment: sometimes the tapping to swap players does not respond. means you are swapping by dragging cells?

Comment: Something like that, just keep the record of the cell's index that need to update, then let the view inside the cell to update, if you push the update to the cell class, it wont mess with your collection view tap/drag...

Comment: will definitely try that, will tell you if it works

Comment: @elk_cloner everytime I tap, the cell changes from red to green or green to red. I don't need to drag the players around

Comment: That seems to work great, thank @Tj3n, silly me, never thought about that. I can give you an accepted answer, if you like. Please bring your comment to be an answer

Comment: You should look into using NSNotifications and observing them instead of reloading the whole UICollectionView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the record of the cell's index that need to update, then get the Cell from collection view, call method ask it to update itself, push the view update to the cell class, it wont mess with your collection view tap/drag...

Reload whole `collectionView` is only needed when whole dataSource change, yours is simply cell-by-cell update as I notice