# SwiftUI - Detect when ScrollView has finished scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I need to find out the exact moment when my `ScrollView` stops moving.
Is that possible with SwiftUI?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993280/how-to-detect-when-a-uiscrollview-has-finished-scrolling) would be an equivalent for `UIScrollView`.

I have no idea after thinking a lot about it...

A sample project to test things out:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { i in
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .overlay(Text("\(i)"))
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach - use publisher with changed scrolled content coordinates with debounce, so event reported only after coordinates stopped changing.

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

UPDATE: verified as worked with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

*Note: you can play with debounce period to tune it for your needs.*

[image: demo]

```
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    let detector: CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>
    let publisher: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never>

    init() {
        let detector = CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>(0)
        self.publisher = detector
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .dropFirst()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        self.detector = detector
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { i in
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .overlay(Text("\(i)"))
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(GeometryReader {
                Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                    value: -$0.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin.y)
            })
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { detector.send($0) }
        }.coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
        .onReceive(publisher) {
            print("Stopped on: \($0)")
        }
    }
}

struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, awkward, this doesn't seem to work in my case. the `print` is never called. Also using an additional gesture to detect when it starts by doing this         ```.simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture().onChanged({ _ in
                print("Started Scrolling")
            }))```

Comment: What is the implementation of `ViewOffsetKey` ?

Comment: @OlegG. ViewOffsetKey  is taken from my another post https://stackoverflow.com/a/62588295/12299030

Comment: Ok, so yeah basically I implemented the same one. But still doesn't work. `Started scrolling` is called but not the stop

Comment: Genius, thank you so much. Using the well known introspectScrollView happen to crash due to SwiftUI dynamic dealloc and this native solution is actually the best to go.

Comment: I found a strange bug here. 
When we package it as a view like `TrackScrollView` with a `binding` / `environmentObject` / `objectedObject`, and we update binding state in `.onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { self.theBindingState = "foo"  detector.send($0) }`, then `.onReceive` will not trigger:(

Comment: The print statements never fire for me in Xcode 13 and iOS 15

Comment: I had problems (in similar code) with onReceive not being called.  (Removing the debounce() call avoided it -- but that's not an option, of course.)  I eventually fixed it by making `detector` and `publisher` @State variables instead of let-properties.

Comment: Why apple doesn't provide its own set of functions just like UIScrollView? And will it do so in future?

Comment: I had the same issue as @ecp above and had to make `detector` and `publisher` @State variables for it to work.

Answer (score 5):

#### One more variant that worked for me, based on @mdonati answer

The **ZStack** solved my problem when I was using **LazyHStack** or **LazyVStack**

```
struct ScrollViewOffsetReader: View {
    private let onScrollingStarted: () -> Void
    private let onScrollingFinished: () -> Void
    
    private let detector: CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>
    private let publisher: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never>
    @State private var scrolling: Bool = false
    
    @State private var lastValue: CGFloat = 0
    
    init() {
        self.init(onScrollingStarted: {}, onScrollingFinished: {})
    }
    
    init(
        onScrollingStarted: @escaping () -> Void,
        onScrollingFinished: @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        self.onScrollingStarted = onScrollingStarted
        self.onScrollingFinished = onScrollingFinished
        let detector = CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>(0)
        self.publisher = detector
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        self.detector = detector
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                .onChange(of: g.frame(in: .global).origin.x) { offset in
                    if !scrolling {
                        scrolling = true
                        onScrollingStarted()
                    }
                    detector.send(offset)
                }
                .onReceive(publisher) {
                    scrolling = false
                    
                    guard lastValue != $0 else { return }
                    lastValue = $0
                    
                    onScrollingFinished()
                }
        }
    }
    
    func onScrollingStarted(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self {
        .init(
            onScrollingStarted: closure,
            onScrollingFinished: onScrollingFinished
        )
    }
    
    func onScrollingFinished(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self {
        .init(
            onScrollingStarted: onScrollingStarted,
            onScrollingFinished: closure
        )
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    ZStack {
        ScrollViewOffsetReader(onScrollingStarted: {
            isScrolling = true
        }, onScrollingFinished: {
            isScrolling = false
        })
        Text("More content...")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you elaborate about what `lastValue` is doing here. Where is it set? Why is it needed? Thanks

Comment: It's defined as State variable on top. It's used to make sure we do not call onScrollingFinished more than once per event.

Comment: This this not always trigger the `onScrollingFinished`, and sometimes it comes just before a new `onScrollingStarted`. iOS 16.4 Simulator.

Answer (score 3):

For me the publisher also didn't fire when implementing Asperi's answer into a more complicated SwiftUI view. To fix it I created a StateObject with a published variable set with a certain debounce time.

To my best of knowledge, this is what happens: the offset of the scrollView is written to a publisher (currentOffset) which then handles it with a debounce. When the value gets passed along after the debounce (which means scrolling has stopped) it's assigned to another publisher (offsetAtScrollEnd), which the view (ScrollViewTest) receives.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ScrollViewTest: View {
    
    @StateObject var scrollViewHelper = ScrollViewHelper()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { i in
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .overlay(Text("\(i)"))
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                
                GeometryReader {
                    let offset = -$0.frame(in: .named("scroll")).minY
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self, value: offset)
                }
                
            }
            
        }.coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) {
            scrollViewHelper.currentOffset = $0
        }.onReceive(scrollViewHelper.$offsetAtScrollEnd) {
            print($0)
        }
        
    }
    
}

class ScrollViewHelper: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var currentOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @Published var offsetAtScrollEnd: CGFloat = 0
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable = AnyCancellable($currentOffset
                                        .debounce(for: 0.2, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                                        .dropFirst()
                                        .assign(to: \.offsetAtScrollEnd, on: self))
    }
    
}

struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on some of the answers posted here, I came up with this component that  only reads x-offset so it won't work for vertical scroll, but can easily be tweaked to adjust to your needs.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ScrollViewOffsetReader: View {
    private let onScrollingStarted: () -> Void
    private let onScrollingFinished: () -> Void
    
    private let detector: CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>
    private let publisher: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never>
    @State private var scrolling: Bool = false
    
    init() {
        self.init(onScrollingStarted: {}, onScrollingFinished: {})
    }
    
    private init(
        onScrollingStarted: @escaping () -> Void,
        onScrollingFinished: @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        self.onScrollingStarted = onScrollingStarted
        self.onScrollingFinished = onScrollingFinished
        let detector = CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>(0)
        self.publisher = detector
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .dropFirst()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        self.detector = detector
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                .onChange(of: g.frame(in: .global).origin.x) { offset in
                    if !scrolling {
                        scrolling = true
                        onScrollingStarted()
                    }
                    detector.send(offset)
                }
                .onReceive(publisher) { _ in
                    scrolling = false
                    onScrollingFinished()
                }
        }
    }
    
    func onScrollingStarted(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self {
        .init(
            onScrollingStarted: closure,
            onScrollingFinished: onScrollingFinished
        )
    }
    
    func onScrollingFinished(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self {
        .init(
            onScrollingStarted: onScrollingStarted,
            onScrollingFinished: closure
        )
    }
}
```

Usage

```
ScrollView {
    ScrollViewOffsetReader()
        .onScrollingStarted { print("Scrolling started") }
        .onScrollingFinished { print("Scrolling finished") }

}
```

Comment: your solution is working perfectly for me. However, it seems to not be able to maintain state of its children. I have added Lottie animation inside the ScrollView and the animation always restarts when I scroll up and down. Details about my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75338453/swiftui-scrollview-with-listeners-not-maintaining-content-state.

Comment: This works better then the solution from @lachezar-todorov

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a scollview with the following code.
And the `"Stopped on: \($0)"` is never called. Did i do something wrong?

```
func scrollableView(with geometryProxy: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        let middleScreenPosition = geometryProxy.size.height / 2

        return ScrollView(content: {
            ScrollViewReader(content: { scrollViewProxy in
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20, content: {
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: geometryProxy.size.height * 0.4)
                    ForEach(viewModel.fragments, id: \.id) { fragment in
                        Text(fragment.content) // Outside of geometry ready to set the natural size
                            .opacity(0)
                            .overlay(
                                GeometryReader { textGeometryReader in
                                    let midY = textGeometryReader.frame(in: .global).midY

                                    Text(fragment.content) // Actual text
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .foregroundColor( // Text color
                                            midY > (middleScreenPosition - textGeometryReader.size.height / 2) &&
                                                midY < (middleScreenPosition + textGeometryReader.size.height / 2) ? .white :
                                                midY < (middleScreenPosition - textGeometryReader.size.height / 2) ? .gray :
                                                .gray
                                        )
                                        .colorMultiply( // Animates better than .foregroundColor animation
                                            midY > (middleScreenPosition - textGeometryReader.size.height / 2) &&
                                                midY < (middleScreenPosition + textGeometryReader.size.height / 2) ? .white :
                                                midY < (middleScreenPosition - textGeometryReader.size.height / 2) ? .gray :
                                                .clear
                                        )
                                        .animation(.easeInOut)
                                }
                            )
                            .scrollId(fragment.id)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: geometryProxy.size.height * 0.4)
                })
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                                           value: -$0.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin.y)
                })
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { detector.send($0) }
                .padding()
                .onReceive(self.fragment.$currentFragment, perform: { currentFragment in
                    guard let id = currentFragment?.id else {
                        return
                    }
                    scrollViewProxy.scrollTo(id, alignment: .center)
                })
            })
        })
        .simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture().onChanged({ _ in
                print("Started Scrolling")
            }))
        .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
        .onReceive(publisher) {
            print("Stopped on: \($0)")
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if I should do a new Stack post or not here, since I am trying to make the code here works.

Edit: Actually it works if I paused the audio player playing at the same time. By pausing it, it allows the publisher to be called.
Awkward.

Edit 2: removing `.dropFirst()` seems to fix it but over calling it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the Answer above worked for me. So with the [help of this medium article](https://saeedrz.medium.com/detect-scroll-position-in-swiftui-3d6e0d81fc6b) I updated my code, I need to pagination for my messages (I am sharing my actual code here that I am using in app).
Comments are added for each line to understand what code is doing.

```
@SwiftUI.State private var scrollPosition: CGPoint = .zero

    var chatView: some View { // Made the chat/messages view separate I am adding this chat view in the body view directly, it was not compiling so I break all views in separate variables.
    VStack {
        if viewModel.isFetchingData {
            LoadingView().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 50)
        } // With the help of this condition I am showing a loader at the top of scroll view
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<(viewModel.messageModelWithSection.count), id: \.self) { index in // Messages has section so used two loops
                        Section(header: headerFor(group: viewModel.messageModelWithSection[index])) {  // This will add the date at the top of section
                            ForEach(viewModel.messageModelWithSection[index].messages) { message in  // These are the messages that contains in the decided date
                                if "\(message.user_id ?? 0)" == "\(viewModel.currentUserId)" { // Sender Id is mine than show messages at my side
                                    MyMessageView(message: Binding.constant(message)) // This structure is define in my app
                                        .onTapGesture { // When user tap on message open the image/pdf in detail
                                            messageHasbeenClicked(message: message) // This method is defined in my app
                                        }
                                } else { // sender id does not match with me, than show the message on the other side
                                    OtherMessageView(message: Binding.constant(message)) // This structure is define in my app
                                        .onTapGesture {// When user tap on message open the image/pdf in detail
                                            messageHasbeenClicked(message: message) // This method is defined in my app
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(180))  // This is done to show the messages from the bottom
                // Detect that is scroll change by user
                .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin) // ScrollOffset Preference Key definition is available below
                })
                .onPreferenceChange(ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                    self.scrollPosition = value
                    if value.y < 10, value.y > 0, viewModel.isFetchingData == false { // Checking that its at top and not other pagination call is send to the server
                        print("Scroll is at top position")
                        viewModel.fetchPreviousMessage(forPagination: true) // It will fetch the pagination result and update the Published Object of messageModelWithSection.
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    value.scrollTo(viewModel.messageModelWithSection.last?.messages.last)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(180)) // This is done to show the messages from the bottom
        .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
    }
}
```

Definition of the ScrollOfSerPrefrenceKey

```
struct ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
static var defaultValue: CGPoint = .zero

static func reduce(value: inout CGPoint, nextValue: () -> CGPoint) {
}
}
```

I hope so it will help out, or you can get more details in the article I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `PreferenceKey` to track the vertical scroll offset of a `View`:

```
struct VerticalScrollOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

Add this `ViewModifier` to allow tracking of a View's vertical offset and call a `scrollPostionUpdate` closure when scrolling has stopped:

```
extension View {
    
    func onScrollEnded(in coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace, onScrollEnded: @escaping (CGFloat) -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(OnVerticalScrollEnded(coordinateSpace: coordinateSpace, scrollPostionUpdate: onScrollEnded))
    }
}

final class OnVerticalScrollEndedOffsetTracker: ObservableObject {
    let scrollViewVerticalOffset = CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>(0)
    
    func updateOffset(_ offset: CGFloat) {
        scrollViewVerticalOffset.send(offset)
    }
}

struct OnVerticalScrollEnded: ViewModifier {
    let coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace
    let scrollPostionUpdate: (CGFloat) -> Void
    @StateObject private var offsetTracker = OnVerticalScrollEndedOffsetTracker()
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
                    Color.clear.preference(key: VerticalScrollOffsetKey.self, value: abs(geometry.frame(in: coordinateSpace).origin.y))
                })
            )
            .onPreferenceChange(VerticalScrollOffsetKey.self, perform: offsetTracker.updateOffset(_:))
            .onReceive(offsetTracker.scrollViewVerticalOffset.debounce(for: 0.1, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main).dropFirst(), perform: scrollPostionUpdate)
    }
}
```

**Usage**: Add the `.onScrollEnded` modifier to the **content** of the `ScrollView` and give the `ScrollView` a coordinateSpace name:

```
struct ScrollingEndedView: View {
    private let coordinateSpaceName = "scrollingEndedView_coordinateSpace"
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { rowNum in
                    Text("Row \(rowNum)")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding(.vertical)
                        .background(Color.orange)
                }
            }
            .onScrollEnded(in: .named(coordinateSpaceName), onScrollEnded: updateScrollPosition(_:))
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: coordinateSpaceName) // add the coordinateSpaceName to the ScrollView itself
    }
    
    private func updateScrollPosition(_ position: CGFloat) {
        print("scrolling ended @: \(position)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote reused solution based on Asperi's answer

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct TrackableScrollView<Content> : View where Content : View {

    private let axes: Axis.Set
    private let showsIndicators: Bool
    private let onStartScroll: () -> Void
    private let onEndScroll: () -> Void
    private let content: () -> Content

    private let detector: CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>
    private let smallDelayOffsetChangePublisher: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never>
    private let bigDelayOffsetChangePublisher: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never>

    @State private var isScrolling = false

    init(
        _ axes: Axis.Set = .vertical,
        showsIndicators: Bool = true,
        onStartScroll: @escaping () -> Void,
        onEndScroll: @escaping () -> Void,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self.axes = axes
        self.showsIndicators = showsIndicators
        self.onStartScroll = onStartScroll
        self.onEndScroll = onEndScroll
        self.content = content

        let detector = CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>(0)
        self.smallDelayOffsetChangePublisher = detector
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.01), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .dropFirst()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        self.bigDelayOffsetChangePublisher = detector
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .dropFirst()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        self.detector = detector
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(axes, showsIndicators: showsIndicators, content: {
            content()
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(
                            key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                            value: -$0.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin.y
                        )
                })
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { detector.send($0) }
        })

        .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
        .onReceive(smallDelayOffsetChangePublisher) { _ in
            guard !isScrolling else { return }
            isScrolling = true
            onStartScroll()
        }
        .onReceive(bigDelayOffsetChangePublisher) { _ in
            self.isScrolling = false
            onEndScroll()
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

and simple usage here:

```
var body: some View {
        TrackableScrollView(
            onStartScroll: {
                print("scroll started")
            },
            onEndScroll: {
                print("scroll ended")
            },
            content: {
                Text("my content")
            }
        )
    }
```