# SwiftUI ScrollView with listeners not maintaining content state

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiscrollview

I am using a custom `ScrollView` as I need scroll started and ended events, reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73612181/2768604

Below is my own wrapper to use `ScrollViewOffsetReader` from above reference.

```
struct TrackableScrollView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let axes: Axis.Set
    let showIndicators: Bool
    private let onScrollingStarted: () -> Void
    private let onScrollingFinished: () -> Void
    let content: Content

    public init(_ axes: Axis.Set = .vertical,
                showIndicators: Bool = true,
                @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content,
                onScrollingStarted: @escaping () -> Void = {},
                onScrollingFinished: @escaping () -> Void = {}) {
        self.axes = axes
        self.showIndicators = showIndicators
        self.content = content()
        self.onScrollingStarted = onScrollingStarted
        self.onScrollingFinished = onScrollingFinished
    }

    public var body: some View {
        ScrollView(axes, showsIndicators: showIndicators) {
            ZStack {
                ScrollViewOffsetReader(onScrollingStarted: {
                    onScrollingStarted()
                }, onScrollingFinished: {
                    onScrollingFinished()
                })
                LazyVStack {
                    self.content
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its working fine except for one thing. I have added `LottieAnimationView` on the very top inside the `ScrollView`, and when I scroll, the animation resets to its initial state and play again every time. I have set it to play just once.

So, it seems like `ScrollView` is unable to maintain content state properly.

Any idea on what could be the reason?

Edit:

I was able to figure out the cause of the issue and that is scroll start and end events. If I remove `onScrollingStarted` and `onScrollingFinished` callbacks, I dont get the issue. However, those callbacks are needed to perform some actions on the `View`.

Thanks

Comment: What's `LottieAnimationView`?

Comment: I think it's the `LazyVStack` that's responsible for this behavior.

Comment: @meaning-matters Its the Lottie animation. https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios

Comment: @Timmy I am able to reproduce the issue even without `LazyVStack`.